# String formatting for different options in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to print out a string that describes how many items were removed from a list ('count') and how many are therefore left in the list. In order to make it grammatically correct, I have the following code:

```
if count == 1:
    print("\n{} definition was removed. We therefore currently have {} definitions to test...".format(count, len(test_list)))
if count > 1:
    print("\n{} definitions were removed. We therefore currently have {} definitions to test...".format(count, len(test_list)))
```

Is there a more Pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: Welcome to the world of localization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you just have one variable argument `was/were` which changes as per the value of count. To make your code more readable, you can change only the variable rather then formatting the whole message.

```
msg = '"\n{} {} removed. We therefore currently have {} definitions to test..."'
prep = 'definition was'
if count > 1:
    prep = 'definitions were'

print(msg.format(count, prep, len(test_list)))
```

Comment: Could you also explain your solution with a couple of sentences? Such answers are always stronger.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the pluralisation of the world 'definition'

Comment: @BarunSharma what do you mean?